# Create a Layout in A Scroll View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I am new in Android.I want to create this Layout.
[image: Image How I Want to Create]

I have tried this but i am not getting how could i do this .

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

See i have used ScrollView but i am not able to create the design .Please Help me

Comment: What does "I am not able to create the design" mean?

Comment: @Pooja Dubey this is custom list view.check how to make custom list view http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: @blackbelt i am new in android i just need a start help from you guys soo that i can create this complicated layout.Please help me thankfull to you

Answer (score 1):

You should use a custom `ListView` for this functionality, see example - http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Answer (score 0):

You need this

```
<RelativeLayout (root)>

  <LinearHayout (head)>
    ..some other UI tag for page head
  </LinearLayout>

  <ListView />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And also, try to google "android custom listview" for more detail...